# How to upgrade ubuntu 12.4 to 14.4

Tags: upgrade

I bought a new [Dell 3542 laptop](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15-3542-laptop/pd) with Ubuntu 12.04. I want to upgrade it to 14.04. My update manager is showing there are no updates to install. Please tell me step by step how to upgrade. Thank you.

Comment: have the checkmark checked for checking for new releases?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to AskUbuntu! Unfortunately, Ubuntu 12.04 is long out-dated, and has reached its EOL (End of Life), so we no longer support questions about it. What you can do is download Ubuntu from an outside source, and re-install to your PC.

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice 12.04 will go end of life April 2017

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how, I mean should I buy a DVD or download it from ubuntu website. If you suggest to download from website then please tell me how to install. Thank you

Comment: This is not a very good idea to upgrade. You will face a lot of SOLVABLE problems with wifi, touchpad, graphics, etc. So think twice before you do it. This is specific to this kind of Dell comps with preinstalled 12.04

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal window and

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If you are doing the upgrade over SSH it will spawn a new SSH daemon and warn you that you may lose connectivity during the upgrade and tell you how to reconnect.

It's always best to do it locally if you can, but I've done many over SSH connections :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the update-manager-core package:

```
 apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Open the release-upgrades file for editing by entering the following command:

```
 nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Verify that the following line is present in the file, and that Prompt is set to lts:

```
Prompt=lts
```

Exit nano and upgrade your Linode to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by entering the following command:

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation process. You will be prompted as to whether you wish to continue; as you are on LISH, it is safe to continue via SSH.

You may see a message type `y` and hit enter

Verify that it’s running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by entering the following command:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

Comment: It works. My system updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this following
To upgrade on a desktop system:

Press Ctrl +Alt+T(to open a terminal) and type in `sudo update-manager`

Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '14.04 LTS' is available.
I can show a windows in my case(i am already on 14.04 LTS so it will be different for you)
[image]
Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

For more info, visit [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_or_Ubuntu_13.10)

Answer (score 0):

I would comment Ashu's answer, but I don't have the reputation for that, so I post another answer.

Open **update-manager** and click **Settings**.
[image]

As Rinzwind commented at your question, remember to enable **long-term support versions** at **software-sources** settings.
[image]

Then follow Ashu's instructions.

Have in your mind that some of us (Pilot6 also) prefere not to upgrade distributions this way, but doing a clean install. You can do it better if you prepare a boot-USB **before** possibly mess-up your 12.04 system upgrading it to 14.04, using **start-up disk creator** and a proper for your laptop 14.04 ISO, downloaded from http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/.